# Sum of Divisors Multiplicative

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

I wish to prove that the sum of the divisors function, $\sigma(x)$, is multiplicative, i.e. 
$$\sigma(m\cdot n)=\sigma(m)\cdot\sigma(n)$$
if $gcd(m,n)=1$.

I start by claiming that since $m$ and $n$ can be written uniquely as a product of prime factors, let

$$m=\prod_{i=1}^k \, p_i = p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdots p_k$$

$$n=\prod_{j=1}^l \, q_j = q_1 \cdot q_2 \cdots q_l$$

such that $p_i \neq q_j$ for any $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the sum of the divisors of $m$ is

\begin{align}
\sigma(m) = \,\,& p_1 +p_1 \cdot p_2 + p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot p_3 + \cdots + m + \\ 
&p_2+p_2 \cdot p_3 + p_2 \cdot p_3 \cdot p_4 + \cdots + \prod_{i=2}^k \,p_i + \\
&p_3+p_3 \cdot p_4 + p_3 \cdot p_4 \cdot p_5 + \cdots + \prod_{i=3}^k \,p_i + \\
&\vdots \\
&+ p_k +1
\end{align}

Or,
$$\sigma(m)=\sum_{z=1}^k \left(\sum_{h=z}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=z}^h \,p_i\right)\right)+1.$$

Similarly,

$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{y=1}^l \left(\sum_{r=y}^{l}\left(\prod_{j=y}^r \,q_j\right)\right)+1.$$

Then the product $m \cdot n$ will have for divisors every divisor of $m$ excluding $1$, every divisor of $n$ excluding $1$, $1$, and every possible combination of $m$'s divisors with $n$'s divisors. The combinations are given by the product of the two expressions for $\sigma(m)$ and $\sigma(n)$ less one. Then,

\begin{align}
\sigma(m \cdot n)=&\sum_{z=1}^k \left(\sum_{h=z}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=z}^h \,p_i\right)\right) \cdot \sum_{y=1}^l \left(\sum_{r=y}^{l}\left(\prod_{j=y}^r \,q_j\right)\right) + \\[2ex]
&\sum_{z=1}^k \left(\sum_{h=z}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=z}^h \,p_i\right)\right) + \sum_{y=1}^l \left(\sum_{r=y}^{l}\left(\prod_{j=y}^r \,q_j\right)\right) + 1
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
\sigma(m \cdot n) &= \left[\sum_{z=1}^k \left(\sum_{h=z}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=z}^h \,p_i\right)\right)+1\right] \cdot \left[\sum_{y=1}^l \left(\sum_{r=y}^{l}\left(\prod_{j=y}^r \,q_j\right)\right)+1 \right] \\[2ex]
\sigma(m \cdot n) &=\sigma(m) \cdot \sigma(n)
\end{align}
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
My question is two-fold.

$(a)$ Is this a valid proof?
$(b)$ Is the Sigma-Sigma-Pi notation for $\sigma(m)$, $\sigma(n)$ an appropriate notation, i.e. is there a more concise way to express them?

Comment: If the prime factorisations are $m=\prod_i p_i^{e_i}$ with the $p_i$ distinct primes and the $e_i$ positive integers, and similarly $n = \prod_j p_i^{e_j}$, then $\sigma(m)= \prod_i (e_i+1)$  and $\sigma(n)= \prod_j (e_j+1)$.  Since $m$ and $n$ are coprime the $p_i$ and $p_j$ do not overlap, so the prime factorisation of $mn$ is $\prod_i p_i^{e_i} \times \prod_j p_i^{e_j}$ and $\sigma(mn) =  \prod_i (e_i+1) \times \prod_j (e_j+1) = \sigma(m)\sigma(n)$

Comment: Not commenting on your proof or answering your questions, but using a double induction on $m$ and $n$ is an easier way to prove this.