# An anomaly regarding the sum of all divisors that is square-free

Tags: number-theory, intuition, divisor-sum

Let $q(n)$ be the number of integers $m<n$ such that $m$ is square-free.
Let $p(n)$ be the number of integers $m<n$ such that the sum of the prime factors of $m$ is square-free. And let $s(n)$ be the number of integers $m<n$ such that the sum of the divisors of $m$ is square-free. The table shows values of $q$, $p$ and $s$ for some $n$:

```
      n       q       p      s
    100      60      68     24
   1000     607     660    157
  10000    6082    6343   1090
 100000   60793   62352   8097
1000000  607925  618969  64306
```

It's known that the distribution is asymptotically equivalent with a straight line and that $\frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot 100\approx 60.79$ percent of all integers are square-free. So how to explain this anomaly?

> Why is the distribution of square-free sums of divisors so low?

Comment: I'm not sure I grasp what you feel is anomalous.  Your table shows $q(n)$ approaching the prescribed ratio to $n$.  Your final sentence suggests the anomaly is connected to sequence $s(n)$.  But clearly the sums of divisors are not distributed like arbitrary integers in relation to the property of being square-free.  Have I misunderstood your concern?

Comment: @hardmath: the word anomaly is maybe not the right word, but there should be an explanation why $\sigma(x)$ tends to be a non square-free number.

Comment: Do you know how to apply the standard analytic-number-theory tools to your sequences ?

Comment: @reuns: probably not.

Comment: The basic fact about the sum of divisors function is that it is [multiplicative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500089/sum-of-divisors-multiplicative), i.e. $\sigma(mn) = \sigma(m) \sigma(n)$ when $m,n$ are coprime.  It follows that the prime power factors of $n$ determine the factors of $\sigma(n)$, and thus a necessary condition for $\sigma(n)$ to be square-free is that each $\sigma(p^k)$ is square-free (with $p^k$ the generic prime power in a unique prime factorization of $n$).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on hardmath's insightful comment, another necessary condition for $\sigma(n)$ to be square-free is that the values of $\sigma(p^k)$ are pairwise relatively prime.  For instance, almost all of the prime power factors of $n$ would need to have even exponents in order for $\sigma(n)$ to avoid being divisible by $4$.  Consider also that the majority of $n$ have many prime divisors (about $\log \log n$ typically).  So $n$ needs to be "almost" a perfect square (except for one allowable exceptional odd prime and the prime $2$).

This is really quite rare and it would be unreasonable to expect any positive proportion of $n$ to satisfy such constraints.  It’s fairly easy to prove that the density of such $n$ is only $O(x/\log x)$ up to $x$, similar to that of the primes (but with a larger constant in front).